# registro nil despues de post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, views

Quiero editar un registro con una acción en el controlador pero al pasar el registro llega `nil` y por supuesto no lo puedo editar. Adjunto el controlador, el modelo y la vista.

Se puede ver el [código en GitHub](https://github.com/rrg1459/app1.git) (es un código muy básico generado con Scaffold), solo quiero destacar el error que me da.

Estoy usando las siguientes versiones en local:

- ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 5.1.1

**app\controllers\articulo_controller.erb**

```
 def ajustar
    puts '------------------------------------------------------------'
    puts @articulo.inspect
  # @articulo.contenido = "ref:" + @articulo.contenido 
    puts '------------------------------------------------------------'
    redirect_to articulos_url
  end
```

**app\config\routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articulos
   post '/ajustar/:id' => 'articulos#ajustar', as: 'ajustar'
end
```

**app\view\index.html.erb**

```
<% @articulos.each do |articulo| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= articulo.nombre %></td>
    <td><%= articulo.titulo %></td>
    <td><%= articulo.contenido %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', articulo %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_articulo_path(articulo) %></td>
    *<td><%= link_to 'ajusar', **ajustar_url(articulo)**, method: :post %></td>*
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', articulo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**salida del log**

> Started POST "/ajustar/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-23 13:29:28 -0400
>   Processing by ArticulosController#ajustar as HTML
>   ------------------------------------------------------------ nil
>   ------------------------------------------------------------ Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articulos Completed 302 Found in
>   6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>   
>   
>   Started GET "/articulos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-23 13:29:28 -0400
>   Processing by ArticulosController#index as HTML   Rendering
>   articulos/index.html.erb within layouts/application   Articulo Load
>   (2.0ms)  SELECT "articulos".* FROM "articulos"   Rendered
>   articulos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms) Completed
>   200 OK in 640ms (Views: 565.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás asignando valor alguno para `@articulo`, ya que el método `set_articulo` no se ejecuta para la acción `ajustar`, tal como se muestra en esta línea en tu controlador:

```
before_action :set_articulo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Para que funcione, modifica la línea anterior agregando la acción `ajustar`:

```
before_action :set_articulo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :ajustar]
```

Ahora `@articulo` ya será definida en esa acción por lo que dejará de ser `nil`.

Comment: Excelente, muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Hermano es usted un duro